# Android Rearranging Buttons in a LinearLayout via drag and drop

Tags: android, android-layout, drag-and-drop, android-linearlayout

I encountered the following problem while developing an android application.
I have a LinearLayout of multiple ImageButtons (let's call them 1, 2, 3 and 4) and I want the user to be able to rearrange them via drag and drop.

**Basic Layout**

**[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8GFC.png) [2] [3] [4]**

If I were to **pick up [4] and drop it on top of [2]**, I want the Layout to change as follows:

**[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8GFC.png) [4] [2] [3]**

Here is my problem as a basic sketch:

[image]

Is there some kind of class that can help me achieve this?